# Researching Cohen de Murcia in Spain?

Tags: spain

Our family is trying to trace our family ancestry who were of Spanish descent.

Are there any databases that we could research to obtain more information?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols. You mention "Cohen de Murcia" in your title but not in your question. Is it a name, is it a place, or something else?

Comment: Cindy Please clarify whether you are looking for Spanish records or records in other Hispanic regions or elsewhere. There is a tree on Geni.com for a Cohen de Murcia family (going back to the late 1700s), who (from other clues) were Dutch Jews. The family may have been among those who left Spain during the Inquisition. That would put the research period for Spanish records for that family between 1500 and 1750.

Comment: Hi yes I am trying to trace our ancestors who left Spain around 1942 for Amsterdam would you know where we could find out about our Spanish heritage. My email is cindy@freedompaper.co.za thank you very much

Comment: 1942? see answer below. If typo, and 1492 intended, you may need to hire a researcher familiar with old Spanish language and writing and the legal records of the time. And you would be advised to narrow possibilities of city of origin. Rather than commenting, @cindy, add details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

For generic research about Spain a good starting point is the [Spain Genealogy page at FamilySearch.org](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Spain) which provides a:

> Guide to Spain genealogy. Birth records, marriage records, death
>   records, census records, family history, and military records.

and in particular the [Spain Online Genealogy Records](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Spain_Online_Genealogy_Records):

> These are genealogy links to Spain online databases to assist in
>   researching your family history. This online collection has links to
>   online databases and indexes that may include birth records, marriage
>   records, death records, biographies, cemeteries, censuses, histories,
>   immigration records, land records, military records, newspapers,
>   obituaries, or probate records.

You may also want to review previous Q&As which have been tagged [spain](/questions/tagged/spain).

Comment: I think one link to FamilySearch is more of a comment than an answer. Also I'm not sure it's great to answer very broad and unclear questions because it sets a poor precedent for the kind of questions that work for this site. If the OP does not immediately return, then better to put on hold/close as unclear in my opinion.

Comment: @HarryVervet I'm inclined to disagree but, in any event, I think how to handle broad/unclear questions is something better discussed at [meta.genealogy.se].  It has been discussed there previously, but not for a while: http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/how-should-i-react-to-a-question-that-appears-to-show-no-prior-research http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1579/should-we-allow-general-questions

Comment: @HarryVervet I also don't want to see this site filled up with low-quality questions.  Let's talk about it on Meta.

Comment: Meta post is now available at http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/processing-brief-generic-questions